# Start / stop Websphere Application Server (WAS) profile - Unix/Linux

Tags: linux, unix, server, websphere-8, ibm-was

How can I start and/or stop a Websphere Application Server profile on a Unix/Linux using a command line?

Answer (score 2):

**Starting a WAS profile**

```
 was_install_dir/bin/startServer.sh server1 –profileName profile
```

OR

```
profile_dir/bin/startServer.sh server1
```

---

**Stopping a WAS profile**

```
was_install_dir/bin/stopServer.sh server1 –profileName profile_name
```

OR

```
profile_dir/bin/stopServer.sh server1
```